# Spring MVC Interceptor Test

Tags: spring-mvc, interceptor

I have an implementation of **WebRequestInterceptor** to handle common data in my view so i don't need to write it in every controller. The code is below

```
public class CommonDataInterceptor implements WebRequestInterceptor{

    @Autowired
    private BookService bookService;

    @Override
    public void preHandle(WebRequest wr) throws Exception {
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(WebRequest wr, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("randomBooks", bookService.findRandom());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(WebRequest wr, Exception excptn) throws Exception {
    }

}
```

The question is how to test that "**randomBooks**" contains some books. I know how to test attribute in controller using mock but in interceptor i don't know yet

Comment: You create an instance of your interceptor, you inject a mock BookService, you tell the mock service to return some books when findRandom() is called, then you call postHandle() on the interceptor, and you check that the model you passed as argument now contain the books under the randomBooks attribute. Where's the problem?